# How to convert SQLite Blob to GUID using C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, blob, guid

I have an .net mvc application where a table have uniqueidentifier as primarky which stores GUID based values like: "3406B0EA-64B4-EA11-9E56-28F10E1895FF". I have another desktop application which syncs data from main database (SQL Server) To local database (SQLITE) using dotmim sync framework.

After syncing my uniqueindentifier type is automatically converted to BLOB type in Sqlite database and values are storing as binary data.

I want to convert this binary data to GUID and vice versa in my Desktop application using C#, but I am not found any solution after trying tons of examples/solutions.

Here is the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: A GUID is a binary value, not a string. It has exactly 16 bytes. What does `test` contain? Is it a *string* representation of a GUID perhaps? In that case you should load it as a string and parse it with `Guid.Parse()`

Comment: "test" contains BLOB value from database.

Comment: I suspect the code that wrote to the SQLite database stored a GUID *string* as a BLOG, instead of storing the actual bytes. The real solution would be to fix that code and have it write out the 16 GUID bytes, or use the `TEXT` type. If that's not possible, you'll have to convert the 36 bytes to a string (eg with `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(test)`) and then parse it with `Guid.Parse`

Comment: Yes, it contains a BLOB whose length is invalid for GUIDs in binary form. It's valid for a specific string representation of a GUID

Comment: Check [the Wikipedia entry on GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) - it's a 128-bit number, ie 16 bytes. So that BLOB by definition can't contain a GUID. 36 characters is the length [of a formatted GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What do you suggest?

Comment: What I posted in the comment above. Either fix the code that saves the GUID, saving it either as a 16-byte BLOB or a 36-character text, or convert the bytes back to a string and parse them. I also posted the code - how to convert the bytes to a string, how to parse that string

Comment: Sync frame I have used is third party library (https://github.com/Mimetis/Dotmim.Sync) I have posted query to author regarding this, I'll update once I got any info.

Comment: I doubt they're going to change their format. You'll have to decode this into a string and parse it

Comment: "decode this into a string and parse it" how?

Comment: I posted the code already in the 3rd comment. `var str=Encoding.ASCII.GetString(test); var guid=GuidlParse(str);`

Comment: Thanks a lot it works, Please add this as answer with little explanation. Also how to convert back to original format (Then value I have in test).

Comment: [Guid.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tostring?view=netcore-3.1) will format the GUID into a string. [Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Encoding_GetBytes_System_String_) will return corresponding bytes. Since GUID character are in the ASCII range, any encoding return the same bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot Panagiotis Kanavos for providing me solution, Here is my final code:

```
{
     string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteData);
     Guid guid = Guid.Parse(str);
      return guid;
}

public static byte[] GuidToByteArray(string guidData)
{
      return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(guidData.ToString());
}
```

I am using first method "ConvertToGUID" to convert bytes[] received from Sqlite database to GUID. I am using this method when I need to use plain GUID instead of bytes example while bind in dropdowns (Value field).

Second method I am using to convert GUID to bytes when there is a need to store value into database.